# (Java) SQL Query not returning anything at all

Tags: java, sql, database, bukkit

I've got a problem with my SQLite Database. To bring it to the point: Everything is working (executes / create table / ...) except the queries.

Important: autoCommit = False (But it isn't required for the query function i use)

Here's the code:

---=> Database.class <=---

```
package me.Syloh.Core;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import me.Syloh.Core.Customized.LOG;

public class Database {

    public static Connection connection;
    public static String path = "plugins/Core.db";

    public static void setup() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + path);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        DatabaseMetaData metadata = connection.getMetaData();
        ResultSet resultset = metadata.getTables(null, null, "%", null);

        List<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>();      
        while(resultset.next()) {
            tables.add(resultset.getString(3));
            LOG.info("Table '" + resultset.getString(3) + "' has been found.");
        }

        if(!tables.contains("Bans")) {
            execute("CREATE TABLE Bans (player TEXT, date TEXT, sender TEXT, reason TEXT, ip TEXT, time DOUBLE)");
            LOG.info("Table 'Bans' has been created.");
        }

    }

    public static void execute(String execute) {    
        try {

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute(execute); 
            statement.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void execute(List<String> execute) {  
        try {

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            for(String e : execute) { statement.execute(e); }
            statement.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static ResultSet query(String query) {
        try {

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);
            statement.close();
            return resultset;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void commit() {
        try {
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


---=> Main.class <=---

package me.Syloh.Core;


import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;


public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    Plugin Core = this;

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        Database.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {

        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        try {
            Database.setup();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(Core, new Runnable() {      
            public void run() {
                Database.commit();
           }
        }, 60L, 4L);

        Database.execute("INSERT INTO Bans VALUES ('hI', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1)");
        ResultSet rs = Database.query("SELECT * FROM Bans WHERE player = 'hi'");
        try {
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("player"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I've checked out my Database using a SQL Database editor and all inserts were made. But when iam trying to display them, nothing gets displayed at all.

Please help me! Thanks in advance.

Sincerely,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you are closing the `statement`, which will automatically close the associated `ResultSet`:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);
statement.close();  // This is the problem
return resultset;
```

From [`Statement#close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29) javadoc:

> When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.

Having said that, you should never pass around your `ResultSet` object around your methods. This way it would be very difficult to manage resources, as you would have to keep your `Statement` and `ResultSet` objects opened accross methods.

You should rather build some data structure in the same method you are getting the `ResultSet` in, and return that data structure instead.

Also, you should close the resources like, `ResultSet`, `Statement`, and `Connection` in a `finally` block, so as to ensure they are always closed, even in case of exception.

Comment: Oh my god thank you SO MUCH! Worked perfectly, but i realised that SQL is not case sensitive, anyway of adding support for that in your code? (Case Sensitive SQL Queries) because i only saw database side modifications! THX

Comment: *"but i realised that SQL is not case sensitive"* SQL is neither case-sensitive nor case-insensitive in terms of the values in columns. It's down to the RDBMS you're using and the settings being used (sometimes on a per-column basis).

Comment: Also, the more important question is: If i don't close the statement, does it mean that the statement is idling arround somewhere?

Comment: Well sorry, it's no problem that it isn't case sensitive by default. But how do i close the statement if i have to return the resultset first? :/ Thanks for helping!

Comment: @user2671258. First of all, you should not have `ResultSet` as a return value. In fact, you should not pass around `ResultSet`, or `Statement`, around methods. Because, then it would be very difficult to manage resources.

Comment: @user2671258. So, it's better to build another data structure in the same method, and then return it. Secondly, you should always close the `Statement`, `ResultSet` and `Connection` in a `finally` block.

Comment: Does that mean that a finally statement works after a return?

Comment: @user2671258. Yes. `finally` is executed after `return` value is written on the stack.

Comment: Alright thank you SO MUCH! Finally i got it working. This was my first question and i got instant good support for free :D Very nice, thx for replying

Comment: Alright, sorry about that but it isn't returning anything again using this code: (1 second pls, going pastebin)

Comment: @user2671258. Have you just removed the `statement.close()` and  still returning a `ResultSet`?

Comment: @user2671258. That's the issue. Please see my edited answer. If you return the `ResultSet`, the `Statement` object is lost, as it is local varaible, and hence the `ResultSet` is also lost. You should build some data structure in that method only.

Comment: Build a `List<String>` in the `query()` method, and return the `List` instead of `ResultSet`.